# Sending email from a website?

Tags: php, email

how would I go about emailing the text from a `textarea`(HTML) to an email address? preferably including/from their email. I have no idea where to start, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://php.net/mail), try some examples, and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class very easy to use but yet powerfull.